# Ubuntu 18.04 live cd/install gui not showing

Tags: boot, server, graphics, live-usb, gui

I have an asus k53sv laptop with an i7 2670qm and a gt540m gpu and when i try to install ubuntu desktop 18.04 the GUI dose not appear. I press enter to go into live usb and after the splash screen only the default ubuntu wallpaper loads and nothing else. I can see the cursor and pressing the power button just darkens the screen.

I installed ubuntu server with GUI and it dose the same.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you find any luck with this? I started getting this problem once I installed a new graphics card on my pc

Comment: Hi! Yes, it is a bug with nvidia drivers. I pressed enter, typed my password and then I connected a second screen and spammed Windows key + P till I got a signal. It seems that nvidia optimus(a technology that switches between IGPU and EGPU) is not that friendly with ubuntu. My problem was that the laptop's internal screen name was switching back and forth randomly from LVDS-01 to LVDS-02 or even LVDS-1.